# Using USB device on PC in Android Studio Emulator

Tags: debugging, android-studio, android-emulator

I am developing an app that A dongle (USB) device must connect to Android OS supported device(mobile phones, tablets...) via OTG (On-The-Go) cable. The problem starts here. I need to do debug while the dongle is connected to the Mobile phone. Unfortunately, such situation makes connecting mobile phone to PC and debugging method impossible. ( Mobile phone has 1 socket but I need 2, **one for connecting the dongle to mobile phone and other for connecting mobile phone to pc for debugging**)

Is there a way such that the Android Studio Emulator can access to USB device on the PC?

**EDIT** I have found an alternative way like connecting the mobile phone to PC via Bluetooth [which is explained here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html).

**EDIT 2:** A better and clear way : Installing Genymotion and Virtual Box.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (I use daily) is
adb connect phone_ip

The phone should be connected to wifi (the host also).
Lots of sources for that on the net ([here is one](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-debug-your-android-app-over-wifi-without-root))

mordy.